# Clic simple y doble clic en Java

Tags: java, mouselistener

Soy relativamente nuevo en la programación y me propuse como proyecto personal implemetar un explorador de archivos (bastante simple pero con funciones interesantes). Como dice el título, lo estoy implementando en Java. Quiero lograr que al hacer clic en un archivo o carpeta, se proceda a renombrarlo; y cuando se haga doble clic se abra. El problema está en que cuando hago doble clic, el programa primero intenta renombrar el archivo y luego lo abre... lo cual es raro e inapropiado. A continuación dejo el fragmento de código involucrado...

```
filesTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
            // Acciones a realizar en respuesta a un clic único
            System.out.println("Renombrar archivos aún no implementado...");
        }
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
            // Acciones a realizar en respuesta a un doble clic
            openSelectedPath();
        }
    }
});
```

Si es necesaria más información, con placer la proporcionaré.
Gracias de antemano :)

Comment: Para solucionar esto, puedes implementar un temporizador que espere un breve período de tiempo antes de ejecutar la acción de renombrar. Si durante ese tiempo se detecta un segundo clic, puedes cancelar la acción de renombrar y proceder a abrir el archivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando vi la pregunta, dije "vamos a contestar una facilita"... dos horas después, tengo la respuesta.

```
jButton1.addMouseListener( new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
   boolean primera = true;
   int eventos = 0;
   @Override
   public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent evt ) {
      eventos ++;
      if( primera ) {
         primera = false;
         Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer( 1500, e -> {
            if( eventos == 2 && evt.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 ) {
               System.out.println( "clicko dos veces" );
            }
            else {
               System.out.println( "Renombrar archivos aún no implementado..." );
            }
            eventos = 0;
            primera = true;
         } );
         timer.setRepeats( false );
         timer.start();
      }
   }
});
```

Con la variable **primera**, nos aseguramos que el "timer" no se vuelva a disparar hasta que no pase un determinado tiempo, por cada evento del mouse aumentamos en uno la variable **eventos**, una vez terminado el tiempo de espera del "timer", entra en el "if" y según que valor tenga **eventos** emitirá el mensaje correspondiente.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias 

Comment: Un placer maestro!.